# Implementing a "Terms and Conditions" popup in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup, hyperlink

My RoR app requires users to tick a "Terms & Conditions" checkbox before uploading content.

What I'd like to do is to display the "Terms & Conditions" content in a very simple pop-up tab, [as implemented here](http://www.sitepoint.com/perfect-pop-up/) (and without the need for jQuery or any other libraries which, for reasons I won't bore you with, I'd like to avoid) but, being a Rails noob, I'm having difficulties identifying an appropriate, as well as "clean" solution.

The non-Rails HTML is as follows (I've dealt with the JavaScript):

```
<a href="popup_content.htm" onclick="popUp(this.href,'console',400,200); 
return false;" target="_blank">Link which opens popup</a>
```

My issues are as follows:

1. Where do I store the HTML file containing the Terms and Conditions
   text?
2. How do I use link_to to provide a link to the popup in the related
   form?

Beginning with my first query, I need to create a plain HTML page (popup_content), which will only contain an  heading (Terms and Conditions) and paragraph content within a

element. I have a static pages controller, but I don't think it's appropriate to create a terms and conditions View here, as it'll mean the page will be rendered as a standard page with menus and such, as per my other static pages. I tried placing a simple `_terms.html.erb` page in the `Layouts` folder, but this returned an error message when the page was opened in the popup.

So which folder should I put this HTML file into?

I think I've solved my second query, but I'm not sure I'm using the `link_to` Helper correctly:

`link_to "Click me to display terms and conditions", "[wherever the resultant file should` `be]/terms.html", :onclick => "javascript function to display the popup", :target => "_blank"`

Any advice would be useful - Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link_to_function to show the popup: ([See documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function))

> "Returns a link whose onclick handler triggers the passed JavaScript."

In your case:

```
link_to_function 'Term&Conditions', "popUp('/popups/_terms_conditions.html', 'console', 400, 200);"
```

With this you would have to create a directory 'popups' like this: `app/views/popups`, and a partial view "_terms_conditions.html"

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, but I thought link_to_function was removed from Rails 3 (I may be wrong)?

Comment: It is not removed, it is maybe deprecated. You can use a normal link_to, with an onclick event returning false at the end (`link_to 'Terms&C.', '/', :onclick => 'popUp(...);return false; ` )